# How to make sure realm io user can only access certain data in a model

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm still learning how to implement realm.io in my next project. I'm really amazed in the Realm Mobile Platform (offline-sync).

I'm reading https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#access-control but what I need is preventing user accessing certain data in a model. (let's say they only can access data only their own data).

Thank You

Comment: maybe something like this : https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html But in realm.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the Realm documentation. There are a couple overviews on Multi-Realm setups you could check out. They go over permissions and database design.

https://realm.io/docs/tech-notes/multi-realm-cheatsheet/

https://realm.io/docs/tech-notes/teamwork/